# Electrical voltage is between box and wire, not between hot and neutral. Not OK?

Tags: electrical, grounding, old-house, voltage

I live in a house that has significant issues. Here's the current one I'm wondering about.

This electrical outlet box seems to be "live". There is 120v voltage running between one of the electrical lines and the box. No voltage exists between the two wires, or between the other wire and the box. What is going on here? Would this exist because it was originally knob and tube before an upgrade to BX-cable? (I don't see any lot of knob-and-tube though) Just how unsafe is this - can it be closed up and grandfathered in as this is all pre-existing?

How would I test for where the break in the insulation is (thereby causing the neutral or hot wire to run through the armored cable housing)?

Here's a full set of photos of the situation. https://photos.app.goo.gl/PDBPdcyjYsZ1gFh3A
[image]

Comment: It's possible you are looking at wiring for a switch rather than an outlet.  So you're being fooled that what you call the N wire is not going to the panel but rather to an outlet with nothing plugged into it.  It's also possible the N wire is broken or disconnected somewhere.  But the box itself should be connected to ground and that should be bonded to N back at the electrical panel.

Comment: I'll also add that if there is active K&T wiring in this properly, by all means DO NOT just close it up.  It's dangerous and should be replaced!

Comment: Thanks jwh20! That sounds correct - this piece of exposed metal was hooked up originally. I touched a piece of metal to the area and got showered in sparks, so I wanted to enclosed whatever was going on there in a junction box and maybe add the option to put a little light in the closet. httpsss://photos.app.goo.gl/V8ZSZ552Hu1X3hdSA

Comment: By definition it's OLD, it is a fire hazard because it was installed at a time before there were reasonable electrical standards, the insulation is almost always flammable or deteriorated to the point where it's coming apart.  And, as you have noted, there is no grounding which is a safety hazard in and of itself.  Most insurance companies will not insure a property with K&T wiring.  Other than that, it's ok...

Comment: @jwh20 -- never say never -- there are places where K&T was in use up until the 1950s, which leads to oddities like K&T jobs run with plastic insulated wire (instead of the bad old rubber/cloth stuff), or even with grounding wires!

Comment: @PeachesStevechu -- can you get us clear photos showing the inside of the box in question please, and also the inside of the box this run of BX originates at?

Comment: K&T wiring is NOT dangerous if it is in good shape. The NEC still recognizes K&T and it is allowed to stay in walls when doing updates!  I would agree that is probably a switch loop and the bulb is burned out. Having power on 1 wire to the box shows that the conduit is grounded and not a phantom voltage since you have nothing on the other wire. If you can find a non working fixture put a lamp in and then you will measure voltage at that point I would put a switch in, with the power off of corse.